# Migration/upgradation of Oracle DB to Oracle RAC

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, weblogic

We have a requirement where the client is migrating their oracle to support the ORACLE RAC(Real application cluster). Our application is written in java and is currently deployed on weblogic. We have oracle db and our application uses JNDI for datasource lookup.

I just want to understand what all things do I need to keep in mind during upgrade of normal Oracle DB to Oracle RAC.
Can we configure mulidatasource at weblogic server end to support Oracle RAC?
What will be the impact on sequences and other db objects?

Regards,
Vishal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most important is to make sure that sequences are regarded as random key generators and not as a sequence that can be used for ordering .... For example, if you have a column filled with the value taken from a sequence and use that for ordering, be prepared for surprises.

Sequences are - and should be - cached by Oracle instance, where every instance has it's own block of sequence values. This is done to make sure you have the best possible performance and the least possible concurrency. You could define your sequence with options like no caching or even ordered, taking away the benefits of using sequences.

Normally when your application scales well on a single instance, it can work well on RAC. If the reverse is even more true, if your application does not scale well on a single instance database, it will scale worse on RAC.

If possible, use services to make a logical partitioning of your application, where functions accessing for example the orders table are grouped and executed on the same instance, others on an other instance.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the DataSource definition, you can either use the **Multi-DataSource** option or your can use **UCP/Gridlink** configuration which enables various load balancing strategies of the JDBC connections over the RAC nodes.

See

- [How-To: Use Oracle WebLogic Server with a JDBC GridLink Data Source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/wls-jdbc-gridlink-howto-333331.html)
- [Active GridLink for RAC: Intelligent integration between WebLogic Server and  Oracle Real Application Clusters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/overview/activegridlinkwhitepaperoraclenec-1987937.pdf)